# Convert measurements that have aggregate values to changes between measurments

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

Every 5 minutes, my server reports value of total writes to specific hard drive. This value is an aggregate, so when I chart it in a line graph, it always goes up.

[image]

I'm looking for a way to convert those total values to changes between time periods on which measurements are made. So I want to see spikes on my chart when something is written to hard drive and value equal to zero when nothing is written. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[prev()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/prevfunction)

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
range Timestamp from ago(1h) to now() step 5m | extend Value = row_cumsum(rand(100))
// Solution starts here.
| order by Timestamp asc
| extend Value = Value - prev(Value, 1, 0)
| render timechart
```

[image: Graph]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA2WOO27DQAxEe51iyl3AsaQiZa6QJoFbg5YoyYB2KXApfwAf3oTsIkAqguDMe6xr/FBaZkZPRhg5s5KdJe/xLYaF1CADbGIUmdftUinlkfF7TlzMyxhUEmiU0E4RJshyDRHFeMFnwgN8M849DjSvjC%20oXI/dmsqagpP60DZNjFXtn7wNXnVvwcTK%20%20oB0Z4Vp/sfJZWu%20gd%20zQ8sypewLTu0OzTRo%20pBh5gTusnpT4k0W/H5AAAA)